# Multistage Dockerfile with running minimalist server in second stage

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have written multistage Dockerfile, but also I need to keep alive the image, so I decided to write small server:

```
  const debug = require('debug')('http'),
        http  = require('http');


  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;    
  const INTERNAL_HEALTH_PATH = '/internal/health/live';

  debug('Starting HTTP server on port', PORT);
  console.info('======> Welcome in smoke tests space! <======');

  http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); // http header

    debug(req.method + ' ' + req.url);

    if(req.url === INTERNAL_HEALTH_PATH){
      res.end('OK');
    }
  }).listen(PORT, function(){
    debug('Listening on port: ' + PORT);
  });
```

but when I want to execute (in second stage):

```
# Run minimalist server to keep alive Docker's image
RUN node index.js
```

I got:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
```

I understand the issue but how to cope with that efficiently?

Comment: You can’t “keep images alive”: an image doesn’t contain any running processes, and `RUN` commands are blocking.  What behavior are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for good comment. I can describe my goal. I want to have Docker's image which lives forever. The image consists of huge amount of tests and with help REST services I want to execute some selected tests.